# Why do I obtain NaN when I try to perform an arithmetic operation on a value retrieved using jQuery from a an input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am pretty new in JavaScript and jQuery and I have the following problem.

Into a JSP page I have this input tag:

```
<input disabled id="finanziamento" class="rightAlligned form-control"  style="width:60%" type="text" value='<fmt:formatNumber currencySymbol="&euro;" type="currency" value="${progetto.impFin}" />'/>
```

Then into a jQuery script I retrieve the value of the previous tag by:

```
var finanziamento = $("#finanziamento").val();
var valoreSoglia = finanziamento/2;

console.log("FINANZIAMENTO: " + finanziamento);
console.log("VALORE SOGLIA: " + valoreSoglia);
```

The problem is that when I print the values in the console, I obtain the desired value for the **finanziamento** variable but for **valoreSoglia** I obtain **NaN**.

Why is it not a number? What exactly return `$("#finanziamento").val()`? A string? It it is a string is not automatically coerced into a number when I try to do an arithmetic operation on it?

What am I missing? How can I resolve my problem and perform the arithmetic operation?

Comment: What is the exact value that's put in to the `input`, ie. what is the value in `finanziamento`?

Answer (score 0):

Try thi code:

```
var valoreSoglia = parseInt(finanziamento)/2;
```

Value from the textbox might be cosidered as string. Converting it to int will solve your problem

Comment: Beat me by 15 seconds! Haha.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to explicitly cast the number to an int before the operation. Try:

```
var finanziamento = $("#finanziamento").val();
var valoreSoglia = parseInt(finanziamento)/2;

console.log("FINANZIAMENTO: " + finanziamento);
console.log("VALORE SOGLIA: " + valoreSoglia)
```